# Law of cosines on cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

‎Consider‎ the ‎triangle ‎$\triangle‎‎ ABC$ ‎with‎ ‎area‎ $n$. Let $a$  denote  the  lenght of side $A$; and similarly with $b$ and $B$; $c$ and $C$. Denote ‎$\theta$‎‎ as the measure of angle ‎$‎‎\angle C$ between $A$ and $B$. We have the ‎relations‎ ‎‎‎
‎

> $$\cos\theta=\frac{a^2‎+‎b^2‎-‎c^2}{2ab‎}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sin\theta=\frac{2n}{ab‎}‎‎‎‎.$$‎‎‎‎ ‎

Now‎‎ ‎consider‎‎ ‎$r=(a‎-‎b\cos\theta)/c$‎‎
‎and‎‎ ‎$s=b\sin\theta/c‎$‎. ‎T‎‎‎‎he‎‎ ‎law‎‎ ‎of‎‎ ‎cosines‎‎ ‎states‎ ‎that‎‎ ‎$r^2+‎s^2=1$.‎

‎Similarly‎ ‎to‎‎ ‎this‎‎ ‎subject‎,‎‎ ‎‎‎ ‎we consider‎‎ ‎a‎‎ [cyclic quadrilateral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral) ‎with‎‎ ‎sides‎‎ ‎$A,‎B‎,‎C‎‎,‎D$‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎and‎‎ ‎area‎‎ $‎n$.‎ ‎If‎‎ ‎$\theta‎$‎ ‎be‎‎ ‎the‎‎ ‎measure‎‎ ‎of‎‎ ‎angle‎‎ $\angle‎ ‎B‎$ ‎between‎‎ ‎$A‎$ ‎and‎‎ ‎$C$‎ ‎and‎‎ $‎a‎$ ‎be‎‎ ‎lenght‎‎ ‎of ‎$\overline{AB‎‎}$‎‎‎‎ ‎and‎‎ ‎similarly‎‎‎‎ ‎with‎‎ $‎b‎$ ‎and $\overline{BC‎}$‎‎;‎‎ $‎c$‎ ‎and‎‎ ‎$\overline{DC‎}$‎‎;‎‎ ‎$d$‎ ‎and‎‎ ‎$\overline{AD‎}$‎‎. ‎So‎‎ ‎we‎‎ ‎have‎‎ ‎this‎‎ ‎relation ‎‎
‎

> $$‎‎\cos\theta=\frac{a^2‎+‎b^2‎-‎c^2-‎d^2}{2(‎ab+‎cd)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sin\theta=\frac{2n}{ab+‎cd‎‎‎}.‎$$‎‎
>   ‎

Now‎ ‎my‎‎ ‎question‎‎ ‎is‎‎ ‎how‎‎‎ ‎can‎‎ ‎we‎‎ ‎take‎‎ ‎$r‎$‎ ‎and‎‎ ‎$s‎$‎ ‎as‎‎ ‎before‎‎ ‎so‎‎ ‎that‎‎‎‎ ‎$r^2‎+‎s^2=1‎$‎.
[image]

Comment: Did you mean $\;a\;$ is the length of side $\,BC\;$ ? By your first notation, $\,A,B,C\;$ are vertices, not sides...you then also talk of $\;\angle C\;$... your using the same letters to denote all kind of things and your naming of sides isn't standard.

Comment: Please edit in a more descriptive title --- something that actually says something about the mathematics in the question. Also, the tags --- is calculus really involved here? and multivariable calculus? how about geometry, and/or trigonometry?